# How to eliminate sudden changes in a vector in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Assume that I have vector shown in the figure below. By common sense, we can see that there are 2 values which suddenly depart from the trend of the vector.

How do I eliminate these sudden changes. I mean how do I automatically detect and replace these noise values by the average value of their neighbors.

[image]

Comment: Set a threshold you consider large, for instance 0.3. Use find and diff to locate these. X(k)=(x(k-1)+(x(k+1))/2

Comment: @StewieGriffin: thank you for your suggestion. I figure out I can do this job by using diff function like this:

d=diff(A);
index=find(d(:)<-10*mean(d));
A(index)=(A(index-1)+A(index+1))/2;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a threshold, compute the average values, then compare the relative error between the values and the averages of their neighbors:

```
threshold  = 5e-2;
averages   = [v(1); (v(3:end) + v(1:end-2)) / 2; v(end)];
is_outlier = (v.^2 - averages.^2) > threshold^2 * averages.^2;
```

Then replace the outliers:

```
v(is_outlier) = averages(is_outlier);
```