# Identify and store outliers MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Hello I have spectral data collected over time. I want to store the outliers and there index so that the user can see where the outliers are. I have searched on how to find outliers and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

An outlier can be defined as 1.5 times the standard deviation since this is what I've mostly seen.

```
data = rand(1024,20) %spectral data over time
```

Comment: Well...how are you defining an outlier?

Comment: @excaza I will edit the question.

Comment: Have a look at [How to eliminate sudden changes in a vector in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158423/how-to-eliminate-sudden-changes-in-a-vector-in-matlab/38158529#38158529) Is that what you mean?

Comment: Also, `rand` isn't going to be great for a MCVE. It generates *uniformly* distributed numbers.

Comment: Did you try [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html)ing data that's 1.5 times the [standard deviation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html)?

Comment: @excaza I'm just using it as an example.

Comment: @Tall_Programer Do you have 20•1024 data points, or 1024 vectors of size 20, or 20 vectors of size 1024?

Comment: @Lumen 20 vectors of size 1024

Answer (score 2):

If you can upgrade, you can check out the new [isoutlier](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isoutlier.html) and [filloutliers](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/filloutliers.html) functions in R2017a.  Searching for outliers more than 1.5x the standard deviation would correspond to using the 'mean' method for finding the outliers, and specifying the 'ThresholdFactor' name-value pair to a value of 1.5.  If you want a windowed approach, you can instead use the 'movmean' method and specify a window size.